# Is there any way to align data inside a mysql table using python?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU3gC.png)

```
 sql = 'insert into new(Tim,Description) values("{0}","{1}")'.format(dat[0],dat[1])
```

When I tried to see the output ,the data was not displayed properly

[image: this is the error I faced]

Comment: Where did you see the output? web browser?

Comment: I saw it in the terminal

Comment: Add the screenshot of the terminal output and also post how exactly you want the output

Comment: There are three data in it: Good morning,Good afternoon and Good evening along with time.The output is partial and not properly aligned and that's the issue

Comment: That's a string that represents a query. How are you executing the query and getting results from it? There's usually no output from an `INSERT`. You really should be using [the proper escaping method for SQL](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) because this code is vulnerable to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I use cur.execute(sql) for execution. When I did "select * from new" to see the results, there is alignment issue

Comment: ***@pikkip***: Is the output a single record? Can you execute the `select * from new` in `MySQL Command line interface` and add the screen shot to your question?

Comment: A single record with CRLF embedded will be displayed as seen in your screenshot posted. You need to re-format it in the `select` statement.

Comment: Actually they are three different records

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was when I read out the lines of the file, I used line.readlines(). This added some character like ^M to the end of the record due to which there were problems while executing insert query. I used line.read.splitlines() instead of that and I got the desired output.